# Intel intrinsics support for Atom cloverview processor

Tags: intel, simd, sse2, sse3, intel-atom

I have an application which was designed for Sandbridge processors using SSE to AVX, now I want the same application to run on Atom Processors.

I was recently browsing net for intrinsic support for Atom cloverview processors. Every where it mentions it support upto SSE3.

But that means it supports just upto SSE3 or Supplementary SSE3 is included in SSE3.

In Intel Atom architecture manual it says that all Atom processors Support Single-instruction multiple-data extensions up to SSE3 and SSSE3.

Can somebody give me some clarity on the above, as I developing an application and I am not sure whether to include SSSE3 in my application.

If Intel Atom support SSSE3, that will ease a lot of my pain

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloverview, aka atom-z2760 supports SSSE3

See the datasheet from intel
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/atom/atom-z2760-datasheet.html

Search for SSSE3 and it says in section 1.4 under Processor Core

> Intel® Streaming SIMD Extensions 2 and 3 (SSE2 and SSE3) and Supplemental
>   Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (SSSE3) support

Comment: thanks for the reply, it was very helpful. One more thing regarding Intel Atom processor Z2520, the Intel Ark web-site says it supports till SSE3. Should I understand that this processor does not support Intel SSSE3 instructions which is the supplementary set for the SSE3 instructions. I am even trying to locate the data-sheet for this particular processor. If you can help me with this processor as well, I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.
http://ark.intel.com/products/75203/Intel-Atom-Processor-Z2520-1MB-Cache-1_20-GHz

Comment: @Harrisson, according to wiki all Cloverview models support SSSE3 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Atom_microprocessors#.22Cloverview.22_.2832_nm.29

Comment: @Harrisson, in fact every Atom on the list supports SSSE3.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will be very thankful to you if you can help me with any intel's official documents confirming your claims.

Comment: @Harrisson, if you want any more information then earn some more reputation on SO and make your question a bounty question.